# Working out a Google App engine entity's property data type

Tags: java, google-app-engine, reflection

I have this entity - I'm trying to determine the type of its properties - in Google App Engine's internal data-types PREFERRED (as opposed to Java data types).
The below code is obviously simplified. In reality I do *not* know the entity's properties or anything else about it.

```
final DatastoreService dss = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
final Query query = new Query("Person");
final PreparedQuery pq = dss.prepare(query);

for (Entity entity : pq.asIterable())
{
    final Object property = entity.getProperty("some_property");
    // Here I want to determine which data type 'property' represents - GAE-wise.
}
```

In App Engine's [Java code](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/#svn/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/datastore) I've found some hints:

```
DataTypeTranslator
    DataTypeTranslator.typeMap (internal private member)
Property.Meaning.GD_PHONENUMBER
```

I'm unable to link those together into what I need - some sort of reflection.

I wish I was able to do something like this:

```
entity.getPropertyType("some_property");
```

Does anyone know better?

[DataTypeTranslator source code here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DataTypeTranslator.java)

**Edit #1:** *<< 
INGORE this one. It's me who put these postfixes (I was confused by the doc).*
Here's more important info I've found.
I'm getting it in Eclipse' tool-tip mini-window when I point over an entity (one which I just fetched from the Datastore).
The Datastore seems to send it (this payload) as raw text which is nice, maybe I'll have to parse it (but, how do I get it from code LOL).
Pay attention to the types in here, it's written plain simple.
Here it is:

```
<Entity [Bird(9)]:
    Int64Type:44rmna4kc2g23i9brlupps74ir#Int64Type = 1234567890
    String:igt7qvk9p89nc3gjqn9s3jq69c = 7tns1l48vpttq5ff47i3jlq3f9
    PhoneNumber:auih50aecl574ud23v9h4rfvt1#PhoneNumberType = 03-6491234
    Date:k1qstkn9np0mpb6fp41cj6i3am = Wed Jul 20 23:03:13 UTC 2011
>
```

For example, property named `String:igt7qvk9p89nc3gjqn9s3jq69c` has the value of `7tns1l48vpttq5ff47i3jlq3f9` and it doesn't tell its type. Also property `Date:k1qstkn9np0mpb6fp41cj6i3am`.
Property named `Int64Type:44rmna4kc2g23i9brlupps74ir` has the value of "1234567890" and here it strictly mentions that the data type is of "Int64Type".

Comment: Can't you just check what Java type the returned object is? There ought to be a 1:1 mapping between Java and datastore types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm searching for it too.

It's a bit of a hack, but at least my output includes the type (without needing a secret decoder ring).  But my code is slightly different:

```
Query allusersentityquery = new Query();
allusersentityquery.setAncestor(userKey);

for (final Entity entity : datastore.prepare(allusersentityquery).asIterable()) {
    Map<String, Object> properties = entity.getProperties();
    String[] propertyNames = properties.keySet().toArray(
        new String[properties.size()]);

    for(final String propertyName : propertyNames) {
      // propertyNames string contains
      // "com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PostalAddress" if it is a Postal Address
    }
}
```

There seems to be no documents about determining the Property Types [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities.html#Properties_and_Value_Types).